# Python parsing HTML with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, ajax, parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to take specific data from this [webpage][1] and eventually want to put it into a table of my own, except for right now, I just want to be able to get the data that I want to show up. With the code below I am able to get all the teams with class team even to show up, however I want to have both 'team odd' and 'team even' to show up preferably having team odd show up first then team even.

I'm only focused on taking the names out for now. Any help would be greatly appreciated I've been trying to figure this out all day and quite crack it! I just started learning python and don't want you to give me the answer, just point me in the correct direction.

Thanks!

```
import bs4, requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# Scraping all data from website

url = 'http://www.scoresandodds.com/index.html'
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.content
# Taking content from above and searching through it find certain elements with certain attributes

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
table = soup.find('tbody')

for row in table.findAll('tr', attrs={'class' : 'team even'}):
    list_of_cells = []
    for cell in row.findAll('td'):
        text=cell.text.replace('&nbsp;', '')
        list_of_cells.append(text)
    print(list_of_cells)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To just get the names is simple, use `class_="game"`so you get both odd and even then just pull the td with the text name:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get("http://www.scoresandodds.com/index.html").content)

table = soup.select_one("#mlb").find_next("table")

head = ",".join([th.text for th in table.select("tr th")])
print(head)
for tr in table.find_all("tr",class_="team"):
     print(tr.find("td","name").text.strip())
```

Which  will give you:

```
951 SAN FRANCISCO GIANTS
952 PITTSBURGH  PIRATES
953 SAN DIEGO PADRES
954 CINCINNATI REDS
955 CHICAGO CUBS
956 MIAMI MARLINS
957 NEW YORK METS
958 ATLANTA BRAVES
959 ARIZONA DIAMONDBACKS
960 COLORADO ROCKIES
961 SEATTLE MARINERS
962 DETROIT TIGERS
963 CHICAGO WHITE SOX
964 BOSTON RED SOX
965 OAKLAND ATHLETICS
966 LOS ANGELES ANGELS
967 PHILADELPHIA PHILLIES
968 MINNESOTA TWINS
```

To get multiple data, you can pass a list of classes:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get("http://www.scoresandodds.com/index.html").content)

table = soup.select_one("#mlb").find_next("table")

head = ",".join([th.text for th in table.select("tr th")])
print(head)
for tr in table.find_all("tr",class_="team"):
    print(", ".join([td.text.strip() for td in tr.find_all("td",["name","pitcher","currentline","score"]) ]))
```

If we look at the source, you see some class names are repeated like *line*:

[image]

So we can also use the id's to get the current and runline etc.. data using partial id text:

```
for tr in table.find_all("tr", class_="team"):
    print(tr.select_one("td[id*=Pitcher]").text)
    print(tr.select_one("td[id*=Current]").text)
    print(tr.select_one("td[id*=Line]").text)
    print("")
```

Whic would give you:

```
(r) surez, a
8.5o15
+1.5(-207)

(l) niese, j
-108
-1.5(+190)

(l) friedrich, c
9.5o15
+1.5(-195)

(l) lamb, j
-115
-1.5(+179)

(l) lester, j
-156
-1.5(-105)

(l) chen, w
7.5o15
+1.5(-103)

(r) harvey, m
-155
-1.5(+106)

(r) wisler, m
7.5u15
+1.5(-115)

(r) greinke, z
-150
-1.5(+109)

(r) butler, e
10.5
+1.5(-118)

(r) sampson, a
10u15
+1.5(-170)

(l) norris, d
-123
-1.5(+156)

(r) shields, j
10o20
+1.5(+117)

(r) porcello, r
-235
-1.5(-127)

(r) graveman, k
8o15
+1.5(-170)

(r) lincecum, t
-133
-1.5(+156)

(r) eickhoff, j
8.5
+1.5(-154)

(r) nolasco, r
-151
-1.5(+142)
```

You should be able to piece it all together to get all the table data you want.

Comment: Thank you so much, what confuses me is the line,                                    table = soup.select_one("#mlb").find_next("table")                                                                       It makes sense, except for the find_next('table'), is that moving down the rows? I didn't say the table tag anywhere except for at the very top of the page any clarification would be great, thanks again for the help!

Comment: @Beez, the data we want is in the table after the div with that id, if you just select  the table as in `select_one("table")` or `find("table")` you will see we get way more headers/columns not just `Team,Pitcher,Open,Line Movements,Current,Runline,Scores`